Software Poojas and lakshmi?
Is software Pooja to photo with virtual flowers and picture as powerful? Should we take a video and send or show someone? Is lakshmi Pooja for salary and wealth important after undergrad and more important than gayathri Pooja for education for youngsters in college? Is randomly reading 5 lines from 20 line puja in hostels and in science busy schedule sufficient?

If one can internalize the worship by meditation and perform totally Manasika pooja daily ideally at the same time with spiritual emotions or Bhakti, it'd still give results.
